# Select Content Control Dropdown

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Aim:**

Select Control Control (dropdown) with name 'ddMyDropdown and add list.

The only part that does not work is selecting the Content Control Dropdown. I want the control in the document before hand so it's in the right place.

**Tried:** 
I did have Set *objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(ddMyDropdown)* but this adds a new Content Control rather than 'editing' the current one.

**Code:**

```
Dim objCC As ContentControl
Dim objLE As ContentControlListEntry
Dim objMap As XMLMapping
Set objCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ddMyDropdown")
```

'I've also tried SelectContentControlsByTag, Property has Title and Tag
    objCC.DropdownListEntries.Clear

```
'List entries

objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "--PLEASE SELECT--"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Cat"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Dog"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Horse"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Monkey"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Snake"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add ("Other")
```

**Reference:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836949.aspx

Comment: Because Content Control Titles are not necessarily unique, SelectContentControlsByTitle("ddMyDropdown") should return a ContentControls collection, not a ContentControl.You will need at least to work with the first item in that collection, (e.g. possibly SelectContentControlsByTitle("ddMyDropdown").Item(1) - Icannot checkright now. You may also need to do more if the collection actually has more items.

Answer (score 0):

The below works but is there a way to not loop through all content controls...

```
Dim objCC As ContentControl
Dim objLE As ContentControlListEntry
Dim objMap As XMLMapping

For Each objCC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls

If objCC.Title = "ddDropdown" Then
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "--PLEASE SELECT--"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Cat"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Dog"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Horse"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Monkey"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "Snake"
objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add ("Other")
Next objCC

End Sub
```